# Using the python api in c not working on mac

Tags: python, c, python-2.7

I am trying to import my python file that is in the same directory as my main.c file but for some reason it will not work. I keeps failing at PyImport_ImportModule('dizzle').  Any help would be greatly appreciated I'm on a Mac (*I can get this to work on Ubuntu which is strange) I have PYTHONPATH set.

```
mytestfolder 
   main.c
   dizzle.py
```

Here is my main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python/Python.h>

int main()
{ 
  char *xx = getpimacaddress2();
  printf("%s", xx);

}

char *getpimacaddress2()
{



    Py_Initialize();


    PyObject* module = PyImport_ImportModule("dizzle");
    assert(module != NULL);

    PyObject* klass = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "SnowTest");
    assert(klass != NULL);

    PyObject* instance = PyInstance_New(klass, NULL, NULL);
    assert(instance != NULL);

    PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "add_test", "(ii)", 10, 34);
    assert(result != NULL);

    Py_Finalize();

    return PyString_AsString(result);
}
```

Python file dizzle.py

```
class SnowTest:

  def add_test(self, x, y):
    z = x + y 
    return str(z)
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: On my first assert which I think is caused by it not finding my module in the current directory @Vallentin

Comment: You remember to take the path `PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(PyImport_ImportModule("sys"), "path")` and `PyList_Append(path, ...)` the current working directory of your application?

Comment: Check if exception is set (if any) `if(PyErr_Occurred()) PyErr_Print();`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I am still getting Assertion failed: (module != NULL) @Vallentin

Comment: Try using: 
`pName = PyString_FromString((char*)"dizzle");
        assert(pName != NULL);

        pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
        assert(pModule != NULL);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate the problem. However note that I did so on Windows. The solution should be the same. I mentioned in the comments that it could be something with `sys.path`. Which after testing actually was the problem.

Right after calling `Py_Initialize()` do the following:

```
PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("..."));
```

Where you replace `...` with something that retrieves your application's current working directory (Which in your case would be the directory containing the `dizzle.py` file).

You can also check:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("print(os.getcwd())");
```

If it prints the current working directory of your application, then you can equally do the following right after calling `Py_Initialize()`:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(os.getcwd())");
```

Doing either of those makes `assert(module != NULL)` pass for me.

If it does have something to do with `PYTHONPATH` (which I doubt based on your error). Then you can use `Py_SetPythonHome(L"/path/to/python")`.